# Code for finding files in past 10 days?

Tags: linux, centos

Is this the code for finding the files in the folder created in the past 10 days?

`find  -type f -mtime -10`

Also is there a way to make it list the dates next to the files when putting in this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help at all? Good luck.

```
% find -type f -mtime -10 -printf "%TD %p\n" | head
12/15/13 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/extensions.sqlite
12/17/13 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/webapps/webapps.json
12/17/13 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/.parentlock

find -type f -mtime -10 -printf "%c %p\n" | head
Sun Dec 15 01:12:26.0582052077 2013 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/extensions.sqlite
Tue Dec 17 18:18:24.0963021476 2013 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/webapps/webapps.json
Tue Dec 17 18:18:24.0143021458 2013 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/.parentlock

% find -type f -mtime -10 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n" | head
2013-12-15 01:12:26.5820520770 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/extensions.sqlite
2013-12-17 18:18:24.8710214760 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/webapps/webapps.json
2013-12-17 18:18:24.1430214580 ./.mozilla/firefox/3lwboctc.default/.parentlock
```